# How to create a setup file to manage Python sub packages

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python package that I want to use inside another package. ProjA has multiple folder an and modules all the imports work internally. When embeded it inside in ProjB all the imports in ProjA break since they are in a different directory. My Packages are as follows.

```
-Project A
   |-lib
   |   |- __init__.py
   |   |- somefolder
   |         |- __init__.py
   |-otherfolder1
   |    |-__init__.py
   |-__init__.py



-Project B
   |-lib
   |   |- __init__.py
   |   |- Project A
   |      
   |-otherfolder2
        |-__init__.py
```

Do I need to write a setup.py file to fix the imports? How to I get the imports?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why would you want to do this? Why wouldn't you just declare project A a dependency of project B and import it like any other library?

Comment: Can you please explain how I would do this?

Comment: First, set up project A as a package with a setup.py (or some alternative packaging solution like [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)). Then do the same for the second package, specifying the name of your first package (if it was published on PyPI) or the location of the first package as a dependency. You can also just install the first package system-wide or in a virtualenv you use for working on project B. For more information see [Python's Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/).

Comment: Thankyou that helps a lot!!!